# Правила использования подчеркивания "_" в именах

Tags: c++, c, c++-faq

В различных источниках встречаются упоминания того, что нельзя использовать идентификаторы с несколькими подчеркиваниями, или что нельзя называть параметры шаблона `_Ty`.
При этом заголовочных файлах стандартной библиотеки только такие имена и используются.
Почему так? Как надо писать правильно?

Comment: решили расшевелить болото и заодно подзаработать репы на переводах FAQ из SO?

Comment: А как же классическое из C:
`typedef struct _myname {
  //something
} myname;`

Тут мы имеем дело с глобальным пространством имен и одним подчеркиванием в нем.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## C++

В главе *Identifiers [lex.name]* сказано, что некоторые идентификаторы зарезервированы, и могут быть использованы только компилятором и стандартной библиотекой:

- зарезервировано любое имя, которое содержит двойное подчеркивание (`__`), или начинается с подчеркивания и следующей за ним большой буквой;
- в глобальном пространстве имен, зарезервировано любое имя, которое начинается с подчеркивания.

В случае если эти правила нарушены, компилятор не обязан выдавать какие-либо ошибки или предупреждения, поведение программы не определено.

**Примеры:**

```
void _f(); // запрещено
class X {
  int _m; // OK
  int _M; // запрещено
};
namespace N {
  int _1;     // OK
  void _f();  // OK
  class X__Y; // запрещено
}
```

**Почему так сделано?**

Это дает гарантию, что имена в стандартной библиотеке не будут пересекаться с пользовательским кодом. Например если написать

```
#define X
struct Y;
#include <vector>
```

то определение имен `X` и `Y` ничего не сломают в стандартных заголовочных файлах, и наоборот, если написать

```
#include <vector>
struct X;
```

то никакие имена, определенные в стандартных заголовочных файлах не помешают определить `X`.

Также стандартная библиотека может использовать имена вида `::_f` в своей реализации, тогда конфликт имен приведет к нарушению One Definition Rule, что обычно проявляется в виде ошибок линковки.

## C

Аналогичные правила используются и в Си.
В главе "7.1.3 Reserved identifiers" приведен список зарезервированных идентификаторов:

- все которые начинаются с `_` и следующей за ним большой буквы или `_`;
- те которые начинаются с `_` в области видимости файла, и находятся в обычном пространстве имен или пространстве имен тегов (**в отличие от С++, разрешено двойное подчеркивание в середине и в конце имени**);
- имена макросов, приведенные в стандарте, если переопределение не разрешено явно;
- имена с внешним связыванием, приведенные в стандарте, зарезервированы для имен с внешним связыванием;
- имена из стандартных заголовочных файлов, если подключен соответствующий заголовочный файл.

Comment: Я не согласен с формулировкой. "запрещено" это слишком, скорее "не рекомендуется".

Comment: Разве? Так написано в стандарте?

Comment: Нет, это не UB. UB это вполне конкретное понятие, весьма неприятное. Если уж сравнивать, то тут скорее unspecified behavior(хотя тоже не правильно). Кроме того, если стандарт считает `void _f();` нарушением, то я не вижу согласно чему Вы считаете, что он "запрещает" какие либо именования внутри класса? Не поймите меня превратно, я согласен с тем, что не надо так называть, но "запрещено" это неподходящее слово. Никакого запрета, на самом деле нет. И за нарушении оного никакого неопределённого поведения не будет.

Comment: И все же прямого запрета тут нет. Вас просто предупреждают, что *возможны* неприятности.

Comment: Про UB надо полнее цитату приводить: "Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of
behavior or when a **program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data**". И даже UB ничего _не запрещает_; такие ситуации лишь говорят, что детерминированного поведения в кросс-компиляции ждать не стоит. Про `::_f` всё ясно, хотя это и ерунда, т.к. всё стандартное обёрнуто в `std::` и такая ситуация просто невозможна, ну да ладно, в стандарте написано - пусть будет. Мне непонятно, почему Вы пишите "запрещено" для членов класса, что там может случится?

Comment: Согласен, shall not я не заметил. Тем не менее, стандарт декларирует подобное только по отношению к global names. class members к ним не относятся.

Comment: @Abyx, да вижу я всё прекрасно, но ведь секция называется global names. И я понимаю, почему там запреты прописаны и как они могут повлиять на программу(банальное совпадение имён и программа не соберётся), но в классе то какая может быть причина? Класс это пространство имён(фигурально выражаясь), это не global namespace. Т.е. по существу, мы не можем ничего нарушить, т.к. мы не засоряем глобальное пространство.