# Перевод LPTSTR в string и обратно

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте!
Я принимаю сообщение :

```
LPTSTR сообщение;

case 1001://получение сообщения 
        сообщение = (LPTSTR)(pcds->lpData);
         int кол_принятых_знаков = (int)(pcds->cbData);
       InvalidateRect (hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        break;
```

мне нужно его сохранить в vector str(); как это осуществить?
а потом вывести в окно 
`TextOut (hdc, 10,10, str[0], кол_принятых_знаков);` здесь нужно обратное преобразование?

Comment: Вся идея типов с `T`, как например `LPTSTR`, заключается в том, что они могут базироваться либо на обычных символьных типах, либо на широких символьных типах, в зависимости от установок компиляции. Вам это действительно надо??? И если нет, то откуда у вас взялся тип `LPTSTR`? Почему не `LPSTR`?

Comment: У вас и правда имена переменных на русском?

Answer (score 2):

У вас в 2015 году ещё не unicode-ная программа? Вы поддерживаете до сих пор линейку Win9x? Ох. Ну ладно, тогда хорошо, что вы хотя бы используете `std::string`.

Проблема в том, что `TSTR` мапится на `std::string` для неюникодных, и на `std::wstring` для юникодных программ. Вы можете сделать следующий финт, и определить макрос `tstring`, который будет давать вам нужный тип строки:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define tstring std::wstring
#else
#define tstring std::string
#endif
```

Теперь всё просто:

```
tstring message((LPTSTR)(pcds->lpData));
// ...
message.c_str();
```

Но, возможно, более правильным решением было бы вовсе отказаться от поддержки доисторических платформ, и пользоваться только `LPWSTR`/`std::wstring`.

---

Как советует @zenden2k в комментариях, можно просто определить `tstring` как

```
typedef std::basic_string<_TCHAR> tstring;
```

(Обновление: в более новых версиях C++, по совету @ixSci, можно более элегантно:

```
using tstring = std::basic_string<_TCHAR>;
```

Работает по крайней мере начиная с Visual Studio 2012.)

При этом им можно пользоваться:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
std::wostream& tcout = std::wcout;
#else
std::ostream& tcout = std::cout;
#endif

void func(const tstring& t)
{
    tcout << t;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    tstring s = _T("test");
    func(s);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Вот тут развитие этой идеи: [A TCHAR style header file for STL strings and streams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13036/A-TCHAR-style-header-file-for-STL-strings-and-stre). (Хотя я бы не определял символы в `namespace std`.)

---

Вот о [разнице между `TCHAR` и `_TCHAR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463412/276994). (`_TCHAR` предпочтительнее ещё вследствие [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417783/10105).)

Comment: Мне кажется лучше `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;`

Comment: @zenden2k: К сожалению, так будет не очень. Например, методы, принимающие `string` или `wstring`, не примут такой `tstring`. В частности, вы не сможете определить `tcout`.

Comment: >Например, методы, принимающие string или wstring, не примут такой tstring

Чего вдруг? http://codepad.org/s1Jl4PcY

Comment: @zenden2k: Хм, и правда.

Comment: Рассуждаете верно, но Ваши постоянные посылы забыть об `ANSI` ни как не могу поддержать, к тому же, в будущем это вполне может быть `UTF-8`. Только вот за такие небрежные "советы" -1. Надеюсь, их ни кто не примет на вооружение.

Comment: @mega: Ваше право. ANSI умер, земля ему железобетоном. UTF-8 под Windows не будет никогда, забудьте. Так же как и UTF-16 под линуксом.

Comment: "ANSI умер, земля ему железобетоном. UTF-8 под Windows не будет никогда, забудьте" -- надо же, какой бред ))

Answer (score 0):

Написал как-то либу [`cjCore`](http://sitev.ru) , там есть класс `String`. Чуть-чуть посидишь с исходником - разберешься, как работать с юникодными строками в C++11

Comment: Кажется вы домен не продлили