# Преобразование переменной хранящей путь к каталогу c *.exe

Tags: c++

Узнаю путь к запускаемому приложению следующим образом:

```
char szPath[512];
GetModuleFileName(0, (LPWSTR)szPath, 512);
printf("Filepath: %ws\n", szPath);
```

Далее хочу создать строку, содержащую путь к папке с файлом (т.е. до последнего вхождения ):

```
char* Path = strrchr(szPath, '\\');
```

В результате получаю что-то, но не строку. Как мне получить нормальную строку, по которой я смогу открывать файлы, лежащие в папке с моим приложением?

Comment: `char szPath[512];`, `(LPWSTR)szPath`. Ужасно.

Comment: проще путь к исполняемому файлу выловить из параметров функции main/winmain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь юникодной версией WinAPI (а какой ещё, 2016 год на дворе!), то ваши строки тоже должны быть широкими.

```
wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetModuleFileNameW(0, szPath, sizeof(szPath)/sizeof(*szPath));
```

Затем, для нормальной работы со строками используйте `std::wstring`, вы ж пишете на C++.

```
std::wstring path(szPath);
auto lastPos = path.find_last_of(L'\\');
if (lastPos != std::wstring::npos)
    path = path.substr(lastPos + 1);
```

Comment: `TCHAR` нужно, это же WinAPI.

Comment: @ixSci: Я предпочитаю не заморачиваться с поддержкой неюникодных версий и эксплицитно использовать только w-версии. (Поменял `GetModuleFileName` на `GetModuleFileNameW`.) Неюникодная версия работает правильно только на подходящим образом локализованной Windows, и это ужасно. (Например, на немецкой Windows не пойдут русскоязычные программы.)

Comment: Ну я солидарен, в смысле использования, но в качестве советов/обучения других, я бы лучше использовал `TCHAR` — это больше в духе примеров на MSDN

Comment: @ixSci: Это да, читать `TCHAR`, а писать `wchar_t` не комильфо, так и до раздвоения личности дойти можно. А интересно, есть ли ещё `tstring`?

Comment: `using tstring = std::basic_string<TCHAR>;` :)

Comment: @ixSci: Туда же `tcout`. В общем, это превращается в самостоятельную мини-библиотеку.

Comment: Ну да, это всё сишные вещи, они не очень хорошо ложатся на C++. Они вообще плохо ложатся куда-либо за пределами WinAPI

Comment: Гугл подсказал: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434053/10105 :)

Comment: @VladD все правильно нужны широкие строки, только вот **wstring** не имеет метода **find_lastr_of**

Comment: @perfect: Очепятка, нужно `find_last_of`. Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала `GetModuleFileNameA`, раз вы работаете с ASCII-строками.
Потом примерно так, раз вы не очень умеете со строками работать.

```
char* pos = strrchr(szPath, '\\');
if (pos != 0){*pos = 0x00;}
else{//error}
```

Освойте работу со строками и строковыми функциями для char[] или хотя бы для std::string.